# Salesforce Community translations not working

Tags: experience-cloud

I am working on a Experience cloud site where I must display text in English and French, when i add a rich content editor component on the page and add some text in the English page the same is reflecting when i switch to French, similarly when I add French content and switch back to English the French content overrides the English version of my page.
Things I have checked : Languages to be added to the site (English and French)
Things I suspect : We packaged pages from a sandbox and while doing so we had not enabled other languages but we exported pages to lightning pages and pushed it via changesets, but in the destination org we've enabled both languages. Also, as an FYI when we create a new page the translations are working but not for deployed pages.
Can someone tell me what I might be missing here?